Time Machine won't let me restore Sent Mail
I'm on a 2018 MBP running 10.15.7 (Catalina)
I recently moved web hosting for a domain I have an email account on, but forgot to backup my email account's sent mail before I changed hosts, and it's gone at the old host now.  Fortunately (or so I thought), I use TimeMachine and have for years!
So I select my Sent Mail folder in Apple Mail, Enter Time Machine, and after a moment I'm greeted with all my sent mails.  But, the Restore button is greyed out, and I also can't go back in time although I can scroll through on the right side and see all the many, many, many backups that are there (my archives go back to 2022 apparently).
How can I get it to allow me to restore?  It shows me the messages, all 200 of them (it wasn't a heavily used account, but an important one to me), I just can't click restore!
